# How to implement double-word compare and swap in C/Linux?

Tags: c, queue, atomic, lock-free, compare-and-swap

I was reading the paper ["Simple, fast, and practical non-blocking and blocking concurrent queue algorithms"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=248106) and I realized that that they assume that the computer implements the following pseudo-code atomically:

```
CAS(Q->Tail,tail,<next.ptr,next.count+1>)
```

Where Q->Tail and tail are a pointer and an instance of a struct containing a pointer and a counter.

I know that gcc provides a couple of build-ins for single word compare and swap in c. However, is it possible to implement a non-blocking atomic double-word compare and swap from a single compare and swap in c (using Linux)? Is this the right approach to implement the pseudo-code of the referenced paper?

Comment: Since I'm not going to buy the paper, what exactly is `Tail`? Is it really a pointer coupled with a counter?

Comment: Related / near duplicate: [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984153) (C11 `_Atomic` / `stdatomic.h` has equivalent functionality to C++ `stdatomic.h`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any CAS operations that work on two distinct memory locations. However, it's possible the paper is using a struct for the pointer and counter as a workaround to treat both fields as a larger type, and therefore, change both atomically.

Assuming you have a struct of two fields, a pointer and a counter: pointer size of 4 bytes, counter size of 4 bytes; properly aligned without padding to a struct size of 8 bytes. Assuming you also have a CAS operation that handles values of 8 bytes (such as a pointer to a 64-bit integer). You can prepare the struct values separately, and use the CAS operation on the struct as a whole to change two values at once.

Comment: Note: I have not read the paper, just making a guess. I could be wrong or there could be other ways of which I do not know.

Comment: DCAS operates on two distinct operands, but is quite rare. DWCAS(doublewide) operates on two adjacent values, and is equivalent to what you're doing with a CAS wide enough to hold two smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

Gcc also provides built-ins for double-word CAS, you can use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap, if sizeof(*Q->Tail) == sizeof(tail) == sizeof(third_arg) == 8.
So everything works fine if you can increment "next.count" before performing CAS.

Comment: You actually want `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` not the obsolete Sync version.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).  Or *usually* better but maybe not in this case, C11 stdatomic.h for `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` on an `_Atomic struct ptr_and_counter`.  But as with the C++ equivalent ([How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984153)) you need to hack around the API's inability to give you cheap atomic loads of one member of a struct when you just need to read.

Comment: Using GNU C `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` on the whole struct to update avoids ABA problems, but using `__atomic_load_n` on just the pointer member can cheaply load it, instead of trying to atomically load the whole struct and then extract the pointer.  (In C++20 you could express this pattern with `std::atomic_ref`, although ISO C++ might not define the behaviour of mixing atomic access to a struct vs. one member.)